# Is it possible to build a new probability space so that the product of two independent Gaussian r.v. still be Gaussian in the new space?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, geometric-probability, malliavin-calculus

I know that if $X$ and $Y$ are two independent normal random variables defined on the same probability space ($\Omega$, $\cal{F}$,$\cal{P}$), the product may not be normal, but is it possible to construct a new probability space such that $XY$ can be normal in the new probability space? If it is valid, how to construct such new probability space?

I have this question since when I read the proof of Meyer's Inequality using Mathematical Induction, the author seems to use this result to proof it. The book I read is "The Malliavin Calculus and Related Topics" written by David Nualart. Thanks for anyone's help.

Comment: When you speak of normal random variables, I assume that you will certainly have $\Omega=\Bbb R$ and $\mathscr F$ the Borel algebra. There's little room for flexibility in defining the space for $XY$, isn't there?

Comment: In the proof, $(\Omega,\cal{F},\cal{P})$ is (0,1), borel of (0,1) and $\cal{P}$ is the Lebesgue measure. If under this probability space, I can prove my assertion, it's fine for me.

Of course, I open this question here, which I want to know if I can do it for even more general cases.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent normal random variables (with nonzero variances), then $XY$ is **not** normal. To construct some joint distribution of a random couple $(X,Y)$ such that $X$, $Y$ and $XY$ are each normal ($X$ and $Y$ with nonzero variances), if at all possible, seems like a daunting challenge. I very much doubt Nualart needs such a construction in any way.